# Lowercase Redshift column names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, cognos

When I import a table to Cognos Framework Manager (11.0.11), the default column names are lowercase. Is there a way to convert column names to upper case?

I set a session parameter `describe_field_name_in_uppercase` to `on` but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: This question appears to be about how to change the name of a query subject in Cognos Framework Manager.  Not sure what Redshift has to do with it.  The same would be true about lower case column names in any database on any server type.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [describe_field_name_in_uppercase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_describe_field_name_in_uppercase.html) is a setting made in the database or connection, not a Cognos session parameter.  You can try setting this in the data source connection properties.

1. Open Cognos Administration.
2. Go to the *Configuration* tab.
3. Click on the *Set properties* icon for the Data Source Connection.
4. Go to the *Connection* tab.

You'll probably want to set the *Open session commands* property.

You will want to read [the docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cra.doc/c_usecomblocks.html#UseComBlocks).

Comment: this looks promising but I have no idea how to implement it. I place the below block in the open session commands but this caused nothing to display in the table list <commandBlock> 
  <commands> 
   <sqlCommand> 
    <sql>describe_field_name_in_uppercase=on</sql> 
   </sqlCommand> 
  </commands> 
</commandBlock>

Comment: @kabard Just to confirm, after you changed the settings, did you try to import the metadata again?

Comment: I did import again. Didn't work. I just opened a ticket with IBM and will make an update of what they tell me